# What is the safe way to handle long tomcat connections?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, oom

I have a java spring boot microservice, managed in k8s cluster. The application is just a webmvc app (java, tomcat, spring boot, old but gold RestTemplate), that collects required dats abd sends request to another microservice.

There is a problem - the target microservice can suddenly response slowly (several minutes), that causes heap to grow up to limits and lasts with OOM.

Are there any recommendations for such cases? What jvm / app settings can i tune to make app durable to leaks?

Comment: Set an appropriate timeout for connecting to the target mu-service.  Use a circuit breaker like Resilience4J.

Comment: https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j